# How to avoid printing of \n in print statement inside for loop?

Tags: python

I am running this code and keep getting a \n from reading the newline in the csv file, how can I prevent this?

```
with open('test.csv', '') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_file:
        xurl = "/contacts/v1/contact/email/{row}/profile".format(**vars())
        url = HS_API_URL + xurl + APIKEY
        print url
        data = {
            "properties": [
                {
                    "property": "hs_lead_status",
                    "value": "UNQUALIFIED"
                }
            ]
        }
        r = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `for row in csv_reader:` instead of `for row in csv_file:`?

Comment: `.replace('\n','')` or `.rstrip()` should remove those from the ends of lines

Comment: `for row in csv_reader: row=row[:-1]` drops the new_line if it is at the end of the line. If you have new line in between lines you'll need to handle that too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use newline='' when you open file

Like:

```
with open(test.csv, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for line in reader:
                print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your CSV has newlines at the end of each URL or maybe you caught a newline when from your APIKEY. easiest fix I can think of is this:

```
with open('test.csv', '') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_file:
        xurl = "/contacts/v1/contact/email/{row}/profile".format(**vars())
        url = HS_API_URL + xurl + APIKEY
        print(url.replace('\n',''))
        data = {
            "properties": [
                {
                    "property": "hs_lead_status",
                    "value": "UNQUALIFIED"
                }
            ]
        }
        r = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [rstrip](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rstrip.html) from Python. This returns a copy of the string with trailing characters removed. You can transfrom `url` using `url = url.rstrip('\n \t')`

This is how your full code will look after the change.

```
with open('test.csv', '') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_file:
        xurl = "/contacts/v1/contact/email/{row}/profile".format(**vars())
        url = HS_API_URL + xurl + APIKEY
        url = url.rstrip('\n \t')    #New line which removes trailing `\n`.
        print url
        data = {
            "properties": [
                {
                    "property": "hs_lead_status",
                    "value": "UNQUALIFIED"
                }
            ]
        }
    r = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=json.dumps(data))
```